# Multiplication of two tensors

Tags: object-detection, yolo, yolov7

I'm trying to add a new block  in yolov7. I want to multiply the output of this block with the previous layer coming from other layer.

I used mul (previous and output), but how can I modify in order to precise this two layers in YAML file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add this lines `in yolo.py`

```
elif m is Multiply:
    c2 = ch[f[0]]
```

2. Add a class Multiply in `common.py`

```
class Multiply(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Multiply, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.mul(x[0], x[1])
```

3. Add in `Yaml.file` now

```
for example: [[-1, 6], 1, Multiply, []]  # cat backbone P4
```